# Relationship Between AffineTransformation and Polygon's Point

Tags: java, polygon, affinetransform

As a project, I'm attempting to create an emulation of the game Asteroids. Currently, I'm trying to make it so then the spaceship appears on the opposite side of the GUI if the player ever sends himself out of bounds.

However, I've become quite confused between how AffineTransformation's rotate and createTransformedShape function interacts with the x and y points of the polygon.

Currently, I have the spaceship working; it flies in the angle the user specifies it and all the movement involved works fine. However, when I tried to get the lowest X coordinate of the spaceship to compare if it ever goes bigger than the constant `WIDTH`, it returns 780. This happens all the time whether or not I am on one side of the map to the other, it always returns 780. This I find really strange because shouldn't it return the smallest X coordinate of where it currently is? 
[Here is a screenshot of the console displaying that the "smallest x coordinate" of the polygon is 780, despite not being at 780](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA7rt.png)

Can someone explain to me why the X coordinates of the polygon are not changing? I have 2 classes. One, which is the driver classes, and the other which is the ship class which extends Polygon.

```
public class AsteroidGame implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    public static AsteroidGame game;
    public Renderer renderer;

    public boolean keyDown = false;
    public int playerAngle = 0;

    public boolean left = false;
    public boolean right = false;
    public boolean go = false;
    public boolean back = false;
    public boolean still = true;
    public double angle = 0;
    public int turnRight = 5;
    public int turnLeft = -5;

    public Shape transformed;
    public Shape transformedLine;

    public Point p1;
    public Point p2;
    public Point center;
    public Point p4;

    public final int WIDTH = 1600;
    public final int HEIGHT = 800;

    public Ship ship;


    public AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();

    public AsteroidGame(){
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
        renderer = new Renderer();

        jframe.add(renderer);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.addKeyListener(this);
        jframe.setResizable(false);

        int xPoints[] = {800, 780, 800, 820};
        int yPoints[] = {400, 460, 440, 460}; 

        p1 = new Point(400,400);
        p2 = new Point(380, 460);
        center = new Point(400,440);//center
        p4 = new Point(420, 460);

        ship = new Ship(xPoints, yPoints, 4, 0);
        transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(ship);

        timer.start();

    }

    public void repaint(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);



        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.draw(transformed);


        /*
        g2d.draw(r2);
        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.append(r, false);
        AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
        t.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        path.transform(t);
        g2d.draw(path);


        Rectangle test = new Rectangle(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, 200, 100);
        Rectangle test2 = new Rectangle(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, 200, 100);

        g2d.draw(test2);
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 100);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        g2d.draw(test);
        */




    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (right){
            ship.right();

            transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(turnRight), ship.getCenterX(), ship.getCenterY());
            System.out.println(ship.getCenterY());

        }

        else if (left){
            ship.left(); 

            transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(turnLeft), ship.getCenterX(), ship.getCenterY());

        }
        if (go){
            ship.go();

            //ship.x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * 5;
            //ship.y
            /*
            ship.x += (int) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
            ship.y += (int) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
            */
            //System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(ship.angle)) * 5 + "y" + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(ship.angle)) * 5);

        }
        else if (back){
            ship.reverse();
        }
        ship.move();
        //ship.decrement();

        transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(ship);

        if (ship.smallestX() >= WIDTH){
            System.out.println("out");
        }
        renderer.repaint();
        System.out.println("Smallest x coordinate: " + ship.smallestX());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        game = new AsteroidGame();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            System.out.println("I am down");
            right = true;
            keyDown = true;
        }else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = true;
            System.out.println("I am down");
            keyDown = true;
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            go = true;
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            back = true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            right = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            go = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            back = false;
        }
        still = true;
        keyDown = false;
        System.out.println("up");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Ship Class:

```
public class Ship extends Polygon{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private double currSpeed = 0;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public double angle;

    public Ship(int[] x, int[] y, int points, double angle){
        super(x, y, points);
        this.angle= angle;
    }

    public void right(){
        angle += 5;
    }
    public void left(){
        angle -= 5;
    }

    public void move(){
        for (int i = 0; i < super.ypoints.length; i++){
            super.ypoints[i] -= currSpeed;
            //System.out.println(super.ypoints[i]);
            //System.out.println(super.xpoints[i]);
        }
    }


    public void reverse(){
        if (currSpeed  > -15) currSpeed -= 0.2;
    }

    public void go(){
        if (currSpeed < 25) currSpeed += 0.5;

    }
    public int smallestX(){
        int min = super.xpoints[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < super.xpoints.length; i++){
            if (min > super.xpoints[i]){
                min = super.xpoints[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
    public int smallestY(){
        int min = super.ypoints[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < super.ypoints.length; i++){
            if (min < super.ypoints[i]){
                min = super.ypoints[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public int getCenterX(){
        return super.xpoints[2];
    }
    public int getCenterY(){
        return super.ypoints[2];
    }

    public double getAng(){
        return angle;
    }
```

Comment: just as a tip. You seem to define your speed as a magnitude and then use the angle of the ship as direction. This can give some unwanted behaviour. Just because the ship turns doesn't mean it's speed wil be in that direction.

Comment: What unwanted behavior do you specifically mean?

Comment: Well, haven't you ever stopped pressing forward in games like these and turned around? You're not accelerating so you keep moving in the same direction as before, but you can still turn your ship around.

Comment: That's realistic, but you can't do that with your current method

Comment: Oooohhh, I see what you mean. I initially wanted to do that, but I'm currently trying to figure out how movement and rotation works. Frankly, I'm still confused why I'm able to 'move' the spaceship when all my `move` function does is negate the y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work

The affine transformation doesn't actually affect the ship instance, instead it created an entirely new instance, this is why your method doesn't seem to work. To prove this, i have the following code:

```
int[] xPoints = {800, 780, 800, 820};
int[] yPoints = {400, 460, 440, 460}; 

Ship ship = new Ship(xPoints, yPoints, 4, 0);
System.out.println("old points:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ship.xpoints));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ship.ypoints));
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.translate(20, 20);

Shape transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(ship);
System.out.println("new points (unchanged):");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ship.xpoints));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ship.ypoints));
```

Both times, the points are the same.

### Solution

What i suggest you do is instead of thinking of the point as actual points on the screen, think of them as a model, that will also make the physics part easier. We'll center the points around (0,0). And when we need to render it, tranform it to the correct position and rotation.
The points would then be something like this:

```
int[] xPoints = {0, -20, 0, 20};
int[] yPoints = {-40, 20, 0, 20};
```

So now, you don't need to edit all the points when you move the ship, only the rotation and the center. Note that you should translate first, and then rotate.

The fact that these point are around (0,0) is important, because this is the center of your rotation. This is probably why you seem to be able to move at the moment, your rotation is not centered around the center of the ship. And when you rotate and move up, you also move a bit to the right.

This solves our problem, because now you don't need to look at all the points anymore, you can just check the center of the ship. If the center goes out of bounds, move it to the other side.

Resulting in the folliwing simple code (i use 300 here because that's the width and height in my example, change it to your width and height in the actual code)

```
if(center_x > 300)
    center_x = 0;
if(center_x < 0)
    center_x = 300;
if(center_y > 300)
    center_y = 0;
if(center_y < 0)
    center_y = 300;
```

This will take the ship to the other side of the screen when needed. However, we still need to show part of the ship while the other part is on the other side. For that reason, we can just render the ship twice. I hope the following code speaks for itself.

```
Rectangle2D box = transformed.getBounds2D();
//wrap in x direction
if(box.getX() + box.getWidth() > 300){
    AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
    transform2.translate(ship.center_x - 300, ship.center_y);
    transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
    Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
    g2.draw(transformed2);
}else if(box.getX() < 0){
    AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
    transform2.translate(ship.center_x + 300, ship.center_y);
    transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
    Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
    g2.draw(transformed2);
}

//wrap in y direction
if(box.getY() + box.getHeight() > 300){
    AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
    transform2.translate(ship.center_x, ship.center_y - 300);
    transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
    Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
    g2.draw(transformed2);
}else if(box.getY() < 0){
    AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
    transform2.translate(ship.center_x, ship.center_y + 300);
    transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
    Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
    g2.draw(transformed2);
}
```

### Physics

You also requested more info on the actual physics, i'll just give you the formulas (let me know if you need more help). Here, theta is the angle of the ship in radians, where if theta is 0, the ship points up. The x-axis points to the right, and the y-axis points up.

```
a_x = Math.sin(theta)*a;
a_y = -Math.cos(theta)*a;
v_x_new = v_x_old + a_x*timeDiff;
v_y_new = v_y_old + a_y*timeDiff;
x_new = x_old + v_x_old*timeDiff + a_x*timeDiff*timeDiff/2;
y_new = y_old + v_y_old*timeDiff + a_y*timeDiff*timeDiff/2;

x_old = x_new;
y_old = y_new;
v_x_old = v_x_new;
v_y_old = v_y_new;
```

### Final result

I've implemented how the ship class should look, and also tested if the rendering method works.

```
public class AsteroidsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] xPoints = {0, -20, 0, 20};
        int[] yPoints = {-40, 20, 0, 20};
        Ship ship = new Ship(xPoints, yPoints, 4, 0);
        ship.center_x = 100;
        ship.center_y = 100;
        ship.angle = 45;
        ship.speed_x = 30;
        ship.speed_y = -30;

        System.out.println("running...");

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas(ship));
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true){
            long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double timeDiff = (time2-time1)/1000f;
            time1 = time2;
            ship.move(timeDiff);
            window.getContentPane().repaint();
        }

    }
}

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    private Ship ship;

    public MyCanvas(Ship ship){
        this.ship = ship;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.translate(ship.center_x, ship.center_y);
        transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
        Shape transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(ship);
        g2.draw(transformed);

        Rectangle2D box = transformed.getBounds2D();
        //wrap in x direction
        if(box.getX() + box.getWidth() > 300){
            AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
            transform2.translate(ship.center_x - 300, ship.center_y);
            transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
            Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
            g2.draw(transformed2);
        }else if(box.getX() < 0){
            AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
            transform2.translate(ship.center_x + 300, ship.center_y);
            transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
            Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
            g2.draw(transformed2);
        }

        //wrap in y direction
        if(box.getY() + box.getHeight() > 300){
            AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
            transform2.translate(ship.center_x, ship.center_y - 300);
            transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
            Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
            g2.draw(transformed2);
        }else if(box.getY() < 0){
            AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
            transform2.translate(ship.center_x, ship.center_y + 300);
            transform2.rotate(Math.toRadians(ship.angle));
            Shape transformed2 = transform2.createTransformedShape(ship);
            g2.draw(transformed2);
        }


    }
}
```

Ship class:

```
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class Ship extends Polygon{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public double center_x = 0;
    public double center_y = 0;

    public double speed_x = 0;
    public double speed_y = 0;

    //the angle of the ship
    public double angle = 0;
    //the acceleration of the ship in the direction defined by angle
    public double acceleration = 0;

    public Ship(int[] x, int[] y, int points, double angle){
        super(x, y, points);
        this.angle= angle;
    }

    public void right(){
        angle += 5;
    }

    public void left(){
        angle -= 5;
    }

    public void move(double timeDiff){
        double a_x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))*acceleration;
        double a_y = -Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))*acceleration;
        center_x = center_x + speed_x*timeDiff + a_x*timeDiff*timeDiff/2;
        center_y = center_y + speed_y*timeDiff + a_y*timeDiff*timeDiff/2;
        speed_x = speed_x + a_x*timeDiff;
        speed_y = speed_y + a_y*timeDiff;

        if(center_x > 300)
            center_x = 0;
        if(center_x < 0)
            center_x = 300;
        if(center_y > 300)
            center_y = 0;
        if(center_y < 0)
            center_y = 300;
    }


    public void reverse(){
        acceleration = -1;
    }

    public void go(){
        acceleration = 1;
    }

    public void stop(){
        acceleration = 0;
    }

    public int getCenterX(){
        return (int) Math.round(center_x);
    }
    public int getCenterY(){
        return (int) Math.round(center_y);
    }

    public double getAng(){
        return angle;
    }

}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to set the x and y coordinate to something? Again, I wanted to make it that if your ship goes out of the screen, you would come back in on the opposite side.

Comment: You can try just looking a the center. If the center goes outside the screen, you come out the other side.

Comment: If you copy the polygon multiple (9 to be exact) times at different positions, you can create a smooth effect where the ship is half one side and half on the other.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set the x and y axis to specific coordinates. In addition, can you explain why the ship is able to move at different angles when my `move` function only negates the y axis

Comment: First of all, I'm astonished by the amount you've given to me so far so thank you. However, your ship class code doesn't work and I even tried fiddling around with it. All I want to know is to how you can directly move the `ship` to a specific location once it goes out of bounds. I added this so far, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `if (transformed.getBounds2D().getX() > WIDTH){
         transform.translate(0, WIDTH);
  }
  else if (transformed.getBounds2D().getX() < 0){
         transform.translate(0, WIDTH);
  }
  else if (transformed.getBounds2D().getY() < 0){
         transform.translate(0, HEIGHT);
  }
  else if (transformed.getBounds2D().getY() > HEIGHT){
         transform.translate(0, HEIGHT);
  }`

Comment: In addition, the movement is working the way I want it to be. Maybe later I can change it so then the only way to change direction is to first rotate the ship then move forward, but for now all i want to know is how I can send it to the other side. I've tried the code above and also just directly setting `ship`'s x and y coord arrays to the specific area.

Comment: Marcues Fong, if i'm right, then your ship won't move correctly anymore if it's centered and you need to center it for this method to work.

Comment: As for the code you tried, several things: first of all, you seem to have forgotten some "-", when the minimum x is larger than WIDTH, you add (0,WIDTH) when you should be adding (-WIDTH, 0).

Comment: Secondly, you need to understand that affine transformations are not commutative, that means, if you do a rotation first and then a translation, it will be different than if you did the translation first. This means that when your ship is looking down, and you translate along (0,1) it will actually go in the other direction.

Comment: @MarcusFong I've implemented a simple center bases method in the code i provided.

Comment: @MarcusFong i've also implemented intermediate wrapping

Comment: Okay, thanks for telling me that you need to rotate first then translate. I think I got it now. I'll tell u if anything goes wrong again. Thanks so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MarcusFong you may have misunderstood me. You need to translate first, then rotate. This may not seem logical but it has to do with relative axis and stuff.